# Create a new table oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Hello I recently changed companies and the databases as well. Having worked with postgres so far, oracle is still fuzzy to me, so here I am stuck with creating a table. This is my SQL attempt :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE binaries_seq;
      CREATE TABLE binaries (
       id       NUMBER DEFAULT binaries_seq.NEXTVAL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       data     BLOB NOT NULL
      )
```

Hardly descriptive error shows up :

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Even found an article suggesting this approach :
http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1.php

What am I doing wrong? I was trying to create a table having one blob field and an id field.

This is my oracle version :

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, as per your tag, not using Oracle 12c.

The syntax `id NUMBER DEFAULT t1_seq.NEXTVAL,` is only valid from 12c onwards, so you get an error.

On Oracle 11 and prior, you want to use an insert trigger to apply the sequence's `nextval` to the primary key:

```
create or replace trigger binaries_ins
  before insert on binaries
  for each row
  when (new.id is null)
begin

  select binaries_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;

end binaries_ins;
```